# Dijkstra Algorithm's source node and graph for grid problem

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

[My grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqOz9.png)

Im trying to implement Dijkstra algorithm for grid-like graph attached above to find shortest path from source node to every other node. Having watched many tutorials I fail to understand how I am supposed to define my starting node and graph.

As far as I understand grid doesnt change how algorithm/implementation works. In every tutorial I read/watched source is always "0". For example I read this: [Javatpoint article](https://www.javatpoint.com/dijkstra-algorithm-java). This is their input: [Javapoint graph,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jEQy.png) [Javatpoint Driver class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oox01.png).

So I wonder do the order of rows in input 'graph' matter? Does first row always have to be the row of source node?

This is my attempt at implementing driver class for my grid:

```
        int grph[][] = new int[][] {
    //S  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K
    { 0,-1,-1, 1,-1,-1, 1, 1,-1,-1, 2,-1 }, // S
    {-1, 0, 1,-1,-1, 4,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1 }, // A
    {-1, 1, 0, 4,-1,-1, 9,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1 }, // B
    { 1,-1, 4, 0, 3,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1 }, // C
    {-1,-1,-1, 3, 0,-1,-1, 8,-1,-1,-1,-1 }, // D
    {-1, 4,-1,-1,-1, 0, 2,-1, 2,-1,-1,-1 }, // E
    { 1,-1, 9,-1,-1, 2, 0,-1,-1, 3,-1,-1 }, // F
    { 1,-1,-1,-1, 8,-1,-1, 0,-1,-1,-1, 6 }, // G
    {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 2,-1,-1, 0, 1,-1,-1 }, // H
    {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 3,-1, 1, 0, 2,-1 }, // I
    { 2,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 2, 0, 2 }, // J
    {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 6,-1,-1, 2, 0 }, // K
    };

    DijkstraExample obj = new DijkstraExample();
    obj.dijkstra(grph, 0);
    }
```

Is my graph and source correct?

Comment: [1/2] Your representation of the graph is a variation of an _incidence matrix_ and it defines for each pair of vertices in the graph whether there is an edge and what weight is associated with it. The vertices are arbitrarily ordered and their rank in this order is their column and row index in this matrix, ie. matrix entry `(2,3)` shows the weight of the edge between the 'second' and the 'third' vertex ( original labels: `A` and `B`). If the number of entry `(i, j)` is 0 or positive, an edge exists between the `i`th and `j`th vertex. with the given weight, if it is -1, there is no edge.

Comment: [2/2] The order of rows (and of columns) is significant - you may only change it simultaneously in the same way, which amounts to reordering the nodes. There is no need to have the first vertex as the start vertex for Dijkstra (or any other) algorithm. If you haven't yet done so, consider to consult an introductory _text_ on graph theory to make yourself familiar with the basic ideas.

Comment: No. The matrix entries represent edges, ordered pairs of vertices. The 0 entries in the matrix are precisely those entries where both vertices are the same. The start vertex is the vertex from which you want to compute the shortest path (to some other vertex) from. If you have carefully read the Javapoint article you cite, you'll remember the declaration of the `dijkstra` method you are calling in your code: `void dijkstra(int graph[][], int s)`. The second parameter denotes the vertex where to start your search (labelled `S` in your example`).

Comment: That was bad question. Thanks for answer. So just to be sure; with my current graph(grph), if I were to start from node S on the grid, I would have to set 's' to 0, because my 0th row and column in 'grph' corresponds to S vertix?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do the order of rows in input 'graph' matter?

No.

> Does first row always have to be the row of source node?

No.

For instance, you could reorganise the order, so that "S" is ordered after "F":

```
int grph[][] = new int[][] {
//A  B  C  D  E  F  S  G  H  I  J  K
{ 0, 1,-1,-1, 4,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1 }, // A
{ 1, 0, 4,-1,-1, 9,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1 }, // B
{-1, 4, 0, 3,-1,-1, 1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1 }, // C
{-1,-1, 3, 0,-1,-1,-1, 8,-1,-1,-1,-1 }, // D
{ 4,-1,-1,-1, 0, 2,-1,-1, 2,-1,-1,-1 }, // E
{-1, 9,-1,-1, 2, 0, 1,-1,-1, 3,-1,-1 }, // F
{-1,-1, 1,-1,-1, 1, 0, 1,-1,-1, 2,-1 }, // S
{-1,-1,-1, 8,-1,-1, 1, 0,-1,-1,-1, 6 }, // G
{-1,-1,-1,-1, 2,-1,-1,-1, 0, 1,-1,-1 }, // H
{-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 3,-1,-1, 1, 0, 2,-1 }, // I
{-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 2,-1,-1, 2, 0, 2 }, // J
{-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 6,-1,-1, 2, 0 }, // K
};
```

This involves moving both the S-row and S-column.

You would then call the solver with the appropriate index:

```
DijkstraExample obj = new DijkstraExample();
obj.dijkstra(grph, 6);
```

> Is my graph and source correct?

The matrix and the main code (2 statements) are correct, but much depends on what your class does.